# Mongoose reference sub-document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

is it possible to reference sub-document in mongoose? I want connect created soldier with enemy or player. In my case is easier to insert enemies into GameSchema than creating new model, but I don't really know, if I am able to make "belongsTo" as displayed below.

---

And my second question, is it possible to reference like in /* commented code */ ?

```
var GameSchema = new Schema({
...
    enemies: [{
        level: {type: Number, default: 0},
        position: {...},
        /*soldiers: [{
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Soldier'
        }],*/
    }],
...
});

var SoldierSchema = new Schema({ // soldier unit 
....
    belongsToEnemy {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Game.enemies',
        required: false
    },
    belongsToPlayer {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Player',
        required: false
    },
...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Soldier', SoldierSchema);
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question or provide a more detailed use case? The question is a bit unclear as currently stated.

Comment: Can I do this: ref: 'Game.enemis' in SoldierSchema? Will it work?

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: The `ref` option specifies the Model name for the reference when used to later populate a document so you could only reference the `Game` model from the `Sodier` schema.

Comment: So the solution is to create Enemy model, which will be connected with game and soldier schema?

Comment: Unfortunately that is a design question which without more context is a bit beyond the scope of the original question. Maybe a more generic design question describing what your concerns are would be more helpful?

Comment: I am designing a strategic game, players and enemies have got military... My model GameSchema holds game map and includes enemies as displayed in question. There are several game rooms on server so I've got PlayerSchema with reference `belongsTo { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Game' }` and now I am thinking, how to asign an army unit (for which I have UnitSchema).